# Handling WCS error appeared with different fits file

Tags: python, header, astropy, fits

I am handling two fits file (the header in the following), EXEMPLE case where it does work and the Orion case where it does not work.

The few lines necessary to read and handle the fits.

```py
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

hdul = fits.open(cubefits)
hdul.info()
hdul.readall()  
hd = hdul[0].header
wcs = WCS(hd)
```

For the EXAMPLE (in the following) I obtain a correct output when I print the wcs:

```
WCS Keywords

Number of WCS axes: 3
CTYPE : 'RA---TAN'  'DEC--TAN'  'FREQ'  
CRVAL : 0.70395330810396  0.69721933449752  125.0  
CRPIX : 507.90474039695  503.02270076207  1.0  
PC1_1 PC1_2 PC1_3  : 1.0  0.0  0.0  
PC2_1 PC2_2 PC2_3  : 0.0  1.0  0.0  
PC3_1 PC3_2 PC3_3  : 0.0  0.0  1.0  
CDELT : 0.0013888888888889  0.0013888888888889  1.0  
NAXIS : 1009  1009  181
```

For the Orion case I have an error by launching the same code:

```py
In [94]: wcs = WCS(hd)
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: The WCS transformation has more axes (3) than the image it is associated with (0) [astropy.wcs.wcs]
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: 'celfix' made the change 'Ill-conditioned coordinate transformation parameter'. [astropy.wcs.wcs]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidTransformError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [94], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 wcs = WCS(hd)

InvalidTransformError: ERROR 7 in wcsset() at line 2660 of file cextern/wcslib/C/wcs.c:
Ill-conditioned coordinate transformation parameter.
ERROR 4 in celset() at line 441 of file cextern/wcslib/C/cel.c:
Ill-conditioned coordinate transformation parameters
No valid solution for latp for these values of phip, phi0, and theta0.
```

Here the headers of the two fits files:

```
### EXAMPLE

SIMPLE  =                    T / conforms to FITS standard                                               
BITPIX  =                  -64 / array data type                                                         
NAXIS   =                    3 / number of array dimensions                                              
NAXIS1  =                 1009                                                                           
NAXIS2  =                 1009                                                                           
NAXIS3  =                  181                                                                           
WCSAXES =                    3 / Number of coordinate axes                                               
CRPIX1  =      507.90474039695 / Pixel coordinate of reference point                                     
CRPIX2  =      503.02270076207 / Pixel coordinate of reference point                                     
CRPIX3  =                  1.0 / Pixel coordinate of reference point                                     
CDELT1  =   0.0013888888888889 / [deg] Coordinate increment at reference point                           
CDELT2  =   0.0013888888888889 / [deg] Coordinate increment at reference point                           
CDELT3  =                  1.0 / [Hz] Coordinate increment at reference point                            
CUNIT1  = 'deg'                / Units of coordinate increment and value                                 
CUNIT2  = 'deg'                / Units of coordinate increment and value                                 
CUNIT3  = 'Hz'                 / Units of coordinate increment and value                                 
CTYPE1  = 'RA---TAN'           / Right ascension, gnomonic projection                                    
CTYPE2  = 'DEC--TAN'           / Declination, gnomonic projection                                        
CTYPE3  = 'FREQ'               / Frequency (linear)                                                      
CRVAL1  =     0.70395330810396 / [deg] Coordinate value at reference point                               
CRVAL2  =     0.69721933449752 / [deg] Coordinate value at reference point                               
CRVAL3  =                125.0 / [Hz] Coordinate value at reference point                                
LONPOLE =                180.0 / [deg] Native longitude of celestial pole                                
LATPOLE =     0.69721933449752 / [deg] Native latitude of celestial pole                                 
RADESYS = 'ICRS'               / Equatorial coordinate system                                            
CUBE    =                                                                                                
DATAS   =                                                                                                
DATE    = '2020-03-30 15:48:36.001328' / date of the creation                                            


### ORION

SIMPLE  =                    T / conforms to FITS standard                                               
BITPIX  =                    8 / array data type                                                         
NAXIS   =                    0 / number of array dimensions                                              
EXTEND  =                    T /                                                                         
HIERARCH LASER_SHIFT = '-5.603303303303305' / [sample] Shift between kids and la                         
CONTINUE  '100_S49749_NA_NA'                                                                             
SCAN    = '49749   '                                                                                     
OBJECT  = 'OrionSim'           /                                                                         
OBSTYPE = 'OTF     '           / Observation Type                                                        
OBSDATE = '2022-08-31T00:00:00.000'                                                                      
SITELAT = '-23.00575'          / [deg] Site latitude
SITELONG= '-67.7592222222222'
SITEELEV= '5105.0  '           / [m] Site elevation
PROJID  = 'E-0109.A-0442A-2022'
SCANNUM = '49749   '
OBS-ID  = '49749   '
DATE    = '2023-02-15T11:57:57.513287'
EXPTIME = '395.13672846369445' / [s] Exposure time
DATE-OBS= '2022-08-31T11:01:12.421'
DATE-END= '2022-08-31T11:07:47.558'
ORIGIN  = 'None    '
NINT    = '736     '           / Total number of blocs
NPTINT  = '2048    '           / Number of points per bloc
NSAMPLES= '1507328 '
LABEL   = 'None    '
INTTIME = '0.000262144'        / [s] Integration Time per sample
WCSAXES =                    3 / Number of coordinate axes
CRPIX1  =                  381 / Pixel coordinate of reference point
CRPIX2  =                  649 / Pixel coordinate of reference point
CRPIX3  =        0.00000000000 / Pixel coordinate of reference point
CDELT1  =   0.0011111111111111 / [deg] Coordinate increment at reference point
CDELT2  =   0.0011111111111111 / [deg] Coordinate increment at reference point
CDELT3  =        600000000.000 / [Hz] Coordinate increment at reference point
CUNIT1  = 'deg'                / Units of coordinate increment and value
CUNIT2  = 'deg'                / Units of coordinate increment and value
CUNIT3  = 'Hz'                 / Units of coordinate increment and value
CTYPE1  = 'RA---SFL'           / Right ascension, Sanson-Flamsteed projection
CTYPE2  = 'DEC--SFL'           / Declination, Sanson-Flamsteed projection
CTYPE3  = 'FREQ'               / Coordinate type code
CRVAL1  =        83.8402938843 / [deg] Coordinate value at reference point
CRVAL2  =       -5.18931388855 / [deg] Coordinate value at reference point
CRVAL3  =       0.600000000000 / [Hz] Coordinate value at reference point
LONPOLE =                  0.0 / [deg] Native longitude of celestial pole
LATPOLE =      69.997710986349 / [deg] Native latitude of celestial pole
MJDREF  =                  0.0 / [d] MJD of fiducial time
RADESYS = 'ICRS'               / Equatorial coordinate system
CRDELT1 =                    0 /
CRDELT2 =                    0 /
```

Answer (score 1):

The first warning explains essentially what is happening:

```
The WCS transformation has more axes (3) than the image it is associated with (0) [astropy.wcs.wcs]
```

It's saying there's a WCS for 3 reference dimensions, but the image in the same header contains 0 dimensions (i.e. there is no image).  This is confirmed in the header:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T / conforms to FITS standard                                               
BITPIX  =                    8 / array data type                                                         
NAXIS   =                    0 / number of array dimensions
```

Most likely your file contains an empty primary HDU containing only an informational header, with different data arrays (probably raw data and separate error correction arrays), that share the same WCS.

Comment: When I load a different one (with naxis=3), I still have an error:
```
hd=hdul[1].header
Out[11]:
NAXIS=3 / number of array dimensions
NAXIS1=761 /
NAXIS2=1297 /
NAXIS3  =833 /
In [12]: WCS(hd)
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: 'celfix' made the change 'Ill-conditioned coordinate transformation parameter'. [astropy.wcs.wcs]
InvalidTransformError: ERROR 7 in wcsset() at line 2660 of file cextern/wcslib/C/wcs.c:
ERROR 4 in celset() at line 441 of file cextern/wcslib/C/cel.c:
No valid solution for latp for these values of phip, phi0, and theta0.
```